# ['“test” value must be either True, False, or None.']

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a register API but it returns a error:
**views.py**

```
class RegisterAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        
        user = serializer.save()
        print(user)
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })
```

**Models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username          = models.CharField   (max_length= 200)
    first_name        = models.CharField   (max_length = 300)
    last_name         = models.CharField   (max_length = 300)
    email             = models.EmailField  (max_length=255,unique=True)   
    password_f        = models.CharField   (max_length=100,)
    profile_pic       = models.ImageField  (upload_to = r'Computerizer/static/Oauth/media')
    sub_to_newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    own_pc            = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    active            = models.BooleanField(default=True,null=True)  #can login
    staff             = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True) #staff user not superuser
    admin             = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True) #admin / superuser
    
    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email' #username

    #email and password is requierd by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] #python manage.py createsuperuser

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.email
    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.email
    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
    def get_absolute_url(request):
        return reverse('')
```

**Serializers.py**:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id','username','first_name','last_name','email','password_f','sub_to_newsletter','own_pc')
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'username','first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password_f','sub_to_newsletter','own_pc')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password_f'])

        return user
```

**the error is:**
['“test” value must be either True, False, or None.'] 
it happens with the **password_f** field, I doubled check every thing and it looks fine, for the record i am using django-knox in **DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES**.
Thanks ..

Comment: What is not clear abot the error?

Comment: why i am getting it ?, it should accept string not True False or None

Comment: `admin` is a `BooleanField`...

Comment: ok it is boolean field but it shouldn't be required .. and as i said the error is in the **password_f** field because when i try True it works fine ..

Comment: then you set `blank=True` in the field.

Comment: tried it, it didn't work ..

Comment: on *all* `BooleanField`s?

Comment: yep, Please i need actual help here